# Error after installing the library on my computer , error message :No .egg-info directory found in ....\pip-pip-egg-info-tdu5ru8i

Tags: python

I tried to install a module which i just wrote.
I ran the command in the folder where my setup.py is

```
pip install .
```

and I got the following message:

```
    pip install .
Processing c:\users\sadaf\desktop\r\group
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\sadaf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-tdu5ru8i
```

Now there was a post, which seemed to be relevant to my issue but it was a different one I guess.

What could possible be wrong and what does this error mean