# ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-n_f6amnr

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm, python-poetry

I am using poetry in my project, to know about poetry [here](https://python-poetry.org/).
After installing poetry using [command](https://python-poetry.org/docs/).
Now when I am running `poetry install` & I am getting the following error.

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
                                                     
  • Installing websockets (8.1)                      

  EnvCommandError

  Command C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Scripts\pip.exe install --no-deps file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/pypoetry/Cache/artifacts/f5/4b/eb/5cfd043e0dbfe90c838bc1570b070131b9cc1f0ebf4a45a2c3e0fe9eb9/websocket
s-8.1.tar.gz errored with the following return code 1, and output:
  Processing c:\users\user\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\artifacts\f5\4b\eb\5cfd043e0dbfe90c838bc1570b070131b9cc1f0ebf4a45a2c3e0fe9eb9\websockets-8.1.tar.gz
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-n_f6amnr


  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py:1195 in _run
      1191│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1192│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1193│                 )
      1194│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1195│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1196│
      1197│         return decode(output)
      1198│
      1199│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

Similarly:

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>poetry install                                                                                    
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 29 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing markupsafe (2.1.1)

  Command C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Scripts\pip.exe install --no-deps file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/pypoetry/Cache/artifacts/1b/09/43/f8f36d57c7cc6f6a038e649e082fa3ea231c686664e203db89b869ada7/atomicwri
tes-1.4.1.tar.gz errored with the following return code 1, and output:
  Processing c:\users\user\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\artifacts\1b\09\43\f8f36d57c7cc6f6a038e649e082fa3ea231c686664e203db89b869ada7\atomicwrites-1.4.1.tar.gz
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_5pto6b7


  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py:1195 in _run
      1191│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1192│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1193│                 )
      1194│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1195│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1196│
      1197│         return decode(output)
      1198│
      1199│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

> ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-**n_f6amnr**

The **bold text** in the above error is getting changed everytime I am receiving this error.

I tried to google the solutions, what I found I already applied them but still its throwing me similar error with different dependencies which I`m not even using in my project.

Solution that I found:-

- https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/165 , https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8760
- [install `pysal` but get error report: `ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ygsexy4a`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172243/install-pysal-but-get-error-report-error-no-egg-info-directory-found-in-c)

Few more somehow similar topics though not exactly what I`m facing:

- [Error after installing the library on my computer , error message :No .egg-info directory found in ....\pip-pip-egg-info-tdu5ru8i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154389/error-after-installing-the-library-on-my-computer-error-message-no-egg-info)
- [ERROR: More than one .egg-info directory found in /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-<somehash>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432640/error-more-than-one-egg-info-directory-found-in-tmp-pip-pip-egg-info-somehas)

If anyone from the community could support would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was facing this issue in the latest version of poetry.
I downgraded it to `1.1.13`. 
And its working fine now.

Commands that I used:-

1. To uninstall poetry : `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3 - --uninstall` 
   **NOTE:** If it complain for python, provide path where you have python installed instead of python3 in the command.
2. Reinstalled it : `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | py -`

For more refer [official docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/).

Thank you.